# Argument type 'string' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Collection.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,object>'

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, resharper

so I'm refactoring a old application, and I made a new Sql Helper class to take over the DB work. By now it only contains one method and I don't know why I'm getting the Error that's mentioned in the title.

Here's the code:

```
    public class Helper
{
    private static string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            return ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
        }
    }


    public static DataSet ExecuteDataset(string commandText,params KeyValuePair<string,object>[] paramsList)
    {
        if (paramsList.Length > 0)
            return Helper.ExecuteDataset(ConnectionString, commandText, paramsList.Select(s => new MySqlParameter(s.Key, s.Value)).ToArray());

        return Helper.ExecuteDataset(ConnectionString, commandText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Put the error in the question rather than in the title.

Comment: Which line are you getting the error on? I'd imagine both the `ExecuteDataset` lines since you are passing more arguments than the method accepts (though you have made the second argument params, but you are passing a string as the second argument!)... additionally, you are recursively calling aren't you? *to cut a long story short, even if you made this compile, my prediction is that the stack would explode...*

Comment: Yeah I'm getting the error at the ExecuteData lines, yes the calles are recursive.

Answer (score 1):

`ExecuteDataset`'s `paramsList` are `KeyValuePair`s, but you are passing in a string.

I'm not sure what your goal is, but you have infinite recursion at this point because every path recursively calls `ExecuteDataset` before it returns.